# resultCode from Camera is always 0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

resultCode is always 0 from the camera.

Camera Invoking code:-

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(Constants.ATTACH_IMAGE);
                imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                imageIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                    if (imageIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 1);
                    }
                    imageIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
                else {
                    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(imageIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                        getContext().grantUriPermission(packageName, fileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    }

                    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, Constants.ATTACH_IMAGE);

                }
```

fileUri looks like :-
content://com.dummyname1.dummname2.provider/external_files/DummyName/IMG_SR7896f7f4-8eb7-47bc-990c-d46ad04c2a7c.jpeg

OnActivityResult :-

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode){
            case Constants.ATTACH_IMAGE:

                if(resultCode ==Constants.RESULT_OK){
                    attachmentType="IMAGE";
                    attachment.setEnabled(false);
                    attachLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.successfull_image, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    File actualImage = null;
                    try {
                        actualImage = FileUtil.from(getContext(),fileUri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(actualImage!=null){

                        File compressedImage = new Compressor.Builder(getContext())
                                .setMaxWidth(1920).setMaxHeight(1440)
                                .setQuality(75)
                                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                                .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Constants.SavePath).build().compressToFile(actualImage);

                    }
                    add_Comments_on_Media_add("Photo added!");

                }
                else
                    mediaName="";
                break;
```

Comment: Perhaps the specific camera app that you are testing with cannot support `content` schemes for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: @CommonsWare It is working in some devices, but not working with devices of some vendors, like "Samsung, Xiaomi" etc.

If your suspicion is correct, what can I do to make this work for all devices?

Comment: "what can I do to make this work for all devices?" -- get rid of all of this code. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is unreliable by nature, as you do not control the behavior of third-party apps. Either use a camera library or use the Android camera APIs directly (`android.hardware.Camera`, `android.hardware.camera2.*`).

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you "answer" this question with some code snippet?

Comment: I do not know what sort of "code snippet" you are seeking. Using either of the native camera APIs is well beyond the scope of a "code snippet". Decent [camera libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141?sort=created) have code snippets as part of their sites.

Comment: @CommonsWare
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html 
Mentions ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Why do they do that?

Comment: Because it is the only camera option in the Android SDK itself that is easy. "Easy" does not mean "reliable". For cases where you do not absolutely need to take a picture, and so you can tell the user "sorry, your camera app does not seem to work well, please try another one", `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is OK. But you asked "what can I do to make this work for all devices?", and for that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is unsuitable.

Comment: @CommonsWare What makes this not reliable in some devices? Is it because they have customised OS or Camera App? 
Does this mean ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE will always work with Stock OS?

Comment: There are *hundreds* of different camera apps pre-installed on the thousands of Android device models, and many more available for users to install themselves. Most of those camera apps were written from scratch. There is no compatibility testing, and even Google's own camera app did not support the `content` scheme until a year ago.

Comment: And I have no idea what you think "Stock OS" is.

Answer (score -2):

You use 2 functions: `startActivityForResult()` with 2 request codes which are `1` for API level >= 21 and `Constants.ATTACH_IMAGE` for API level < 21

But the thing is you only handle `case Constants.ATTACH_IMAGE:`

Try this : `case Constants.ATTACH_IMAGE: case 1:`